# __try/__finally equivalent in UNIX

Tags: c, unix, exception

I have a library that written mostly in C, Some parts of it should be thread safe and I use global spinlock to protect the critical section of the code.

Now my problem is:
I should call some callback of the user from inside of a critical section that protected by a spinlock and in case that those callbacks generate an exception, on Windows I have a _*try/*_finally in C to be able to leave the critical section even when an error occurred. Can I accomplish this on UNIX too?

Comment: Strange that this question is getting ignored, there are usually a lot of *nix users around here.  So just a lame comment from an SEH user: it's **very** different on *nix, you must tinker with signals.  A google for "unix trap signals" looks promising.

Comment: @HansPassant, no you don't have to use signals. The answer about `setjmp` should be sufficient. This is the mechanism that is foreseen by C to unwind the stack to a given point.

Comment: Hmm, can you document the unix system call that takes the jmp_buf so it can properly call long_jmp()?

Comment: @HansPassant if a system call doesn't exist, you can make one. But that's not the point. The point was, he wanted an equivalent of __try and __finally in C on linux. This is easy to do using setjmp and longjmp. Many implementations rely on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called structured exception handling. It can be accomplished by using `setjmp` and `longjmp`. It has been used in C for a long time. See this for details: http://www.freetype.org/david/reliable-c.html

Comment: One should perhaps emphasize that such a solution is completely independent of the OS, C only. It should even work with the C versions that are provided by MS.

Comment: @JensGustedt this is the kind of exception handling they used to do way back in 1979