# Leaving ostream Open

Tags: c++, ostream

I created a logger within my C++ program. Based on the code below, are there any issues I should be aware of? I'm mainly concerned with leaving the ostream open for the duration of the program and exiting the program through unclean methods (i.e. x'ing out of the console window). Will the system keep the file open beyond program exit, or will the ostream object be destroyed upon termination (not using the Log::Close() function).

My train of thought is: why open/close it over and over when I could just open it once and close it upon exit?

```
#ifndef LOG_HPP
#define LOG_HPP

#include <fstream>

namespace Log
{
    static const char* File = "Logs\\Log.log";
    static std::ofstream Log;

    void Initialize()
    {
        Log.open(File, std::ios::app);
    }

    void Record(const char* Message)
    {       
        Log << Message;
    }

    void Close()
    {
        Log.close();
    }

}; // namespace Log

#endif
```

Comment: "_I created a logger within my C++ program. Based on the code below, are there any issues I should be aware of?_" Consider asking on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This seems like an answerable, specific programming question that is on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: It looks like implementation is in .h file. That means including .h file into several modules (libraries) make each library has own logger. In this case, there will be several writers to one file. That lead to wrong log file content

Comment: @atrelinski Everything passes through Message.hpp, where the logger is called after a stream to console.

Comment: There will be also problem in multi-threading application, when different threads will call Record simultaneously.

Comment: @LoganWest, even if there is only one header and implementation is in it, problem will exist. To avoid this issue You have to move implementation to .cpp file, leaving declaration in .hpp file.

Comment: It's not logistical problems in the program with leaving the file open you need to worry about. It the problems this poses with other programs trying to interact with the log file. For example, you would not be able to delete the log file without closing the program.  Strongly recommend a flush  after writing a message. Suck to leave the message that explains a crash unwritten in a buffer.

Comment: I believe even when there will be unclean exit, like Ctrl-X or crash, resource will be freed. In other words, ofstream will not be closed, but there will be no problem when next instance of your program starts and write to the same file

Comment: user4581301 is right. There is one more case, when You run two instances of your program in the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ standard does not define what happens when you *exit the program through unclean methods (i.e. x'ing out of the console window).*

However, it does define what to expect when you call [`std::abort`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.start.term#5).

> Calling the function `std::abort()` declared in `<cstdlib>` terminates the program without executing any destructors and without calling the functions passed to `std::atexit()` or `std::at_quick_exit()`.

The most likely outcome of exiting the program uncleanly is what you would expect to see when `std::abort()` gets called.

> Will the system keep the file open beyond program exit

Even though destructors of objects that get called upon cleanly exiting the program do not get called in abnormal termination, the OS will most likely close open file handles. At least that's what I have observed in Windows and Linux. If there are any unflushed buffers associated with output files/streams, you will not see them flushed though.

Answer (score 3):

> Will the system keep the file open beyond program exit

No! After the program exits, independent if it exit in "normal" fashion or will be killed by any OS command or console control sequence, nearly all resources of the program will be freed.

As I know the only not fully removed resource is a named pipe. Normal file handles will definitely be dropped.

But:
It is possible that the last buffer content will not be written to the physical file on disk or wherever you write to. For that reason it will be a good idea to flush() directly after each write.

Answer (score 1):

I would not care that much of the closed file handle. As Klaus said, is more important to flush the stream after writing each message.
On Windows you always can use the SEH frame, __try/__finally block. No matter how you exit the __try, the __finally will be executed, even after throws or return. I would expect you to get similar results with try/catch, just don't use return inside try block. Or take a look here: 
[__try/__finally equivalent in UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001786/try-finally-equivalent-in-unix)